# Does the type of an additivity (finite, infinite) imply anything about the elements being added (finite, infinite, countable, uncountable)?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am working with a problem involving an infinite sample space, a sigma-algebra, a measure assigning the value 0 to finite events, and, assigning infinity to infinite events.

I am asked to show that the measure is finitely additive but not countably additive.

I understand what finitely and countably additive means in regards to taking unions, namely:
Finitely additive = "measure is closed under finite unions"
Countably additive = "measure is closed under countable unions"

But, what I don't understand is if it implies anything about the events being taken unions of. In other words, do finitely additive mean "only taking unions of finite events", and, countably additive mean "only taking unions of countable events"?

Thanks

Comment: Since your space $\Omega$ is infinite, consider the union of all elements in $\Omega$. Each element has finite measure, but countable additivity will obviously fail

Comment: Why would each element have finite measure?  "a measure assigning the value 0 to finite events, and, assigning INFINITY to infinite events." Why will countable additivity obviously fail?

Comment: See Marios' answer below. He is saying the same thing as me but worded a bit differently, so you might understand him better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be an infinite space and chose a countable subset of $X$ say $A=\{x_1,x_2,...x_n,...\}$

Then $+\infty=\mu(A)>\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(\{x_n\})=0$

So the measure is not countably additive.

Comment: I thought finite additivity meant "sum/ union of finitely many EVENTS", but from your answer it seems to me as if it means "finitely many ELEMENTS". Isn't it possible for a finitely additive set function to sum finitely many infinite sets?

Comment: @cjkilimanjaro yes it is possible,but in your case ,this set function(in your post) is not ifninitely additive.

Comment: You have written the sum of all the elements of A (each element in A is finite and therefore the measure equals 0) on the right side of the expression, but then you take the measure on A (instead of taking the measure on "the union of all elements in A) on the left side of the expression. Isn't this wrong to do, shouldn't they be same like in the "definition of" additivity expression???

Comment: @cjkilimanjaro Note that $A=\bigcup_n\{x_n\}$ where am i wrong...??

Comment: Okey, I found were I have been misstaken all along. Just to make sure: measure of A = infinity = measure of union of elements of A. Is this correct?

Comment: @cjkilimanjaro For a set function to be countably additive you must have that the measure of the disjoint union is equal to the sum of  the sets in the union..here it fails